# Styled components and optimization

Tags: reactjs, performance, import, styled-components

I was wondering what method was best performance wise:

### theme.ts

```js
export const colors = {
  black: '#000000',
  ...
}

const components = { ... }

export default {
 ...colors,
 ...components
}
```

### styles.js

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/macro'
import { colors } from 'theme'


export const ExampleWrapper = styled.div`
  // option 1
  background-color: ${colors.black}

  // option 2
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.black};
`
```

I would think that option 1 is better performance wise, since a function is not required for this. However, there is an import statement for option 1. In addition, if you have multiple styles that need colors, I thought 1 import statement would be better performance wise than several functions to fetch theme props.

Is there a definitive answer to what the best way to do this for performance?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but any performance differences between these will be so minimal that I can't ever imagine a scenario where this would be your bottleneck. The classic advice is to measure performance, and only worry about these questions once you identify there is an actual problem.

Comment: Great insight and sometimes I definitely tend to overthink things when developing.